# Validation for jquery. Master validator function or conditional statment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

In my project, I have all my validators working. One per input. My regex is set up, and now I am just working, since I have different validators for each input, do I need like a master validator to run all the functions? What I need is pretty basic, just add a border around the input if either nothing is entered or its not validated right, which is the easy part. But I'm not sure if I need some sort of if statement like the one below, because that means I have to do conditions for each of them, or have some sort of master validator.

github js file: https://github.com/joeEscob1023/interactiveForm/blob/master/js/app.js

```
 if (isValidName(nameInput)) {
     console.log("Please enter a name");
   return;

   } else {
      $(name).css("border", "solid red 1px");
      /* 
    going to create some sort of span to let the user know why there 
      was an issue
    */

   }
```

Comment: You didn't paste the `isValidName` function implementation and you said `regex` that I don't see any `regular expressions` in your code above. Also, your issue is not that clear overall, more clarifications are welcome.

Comment: Please provide more context. I wish what you might be looking for is oninvalid event, assuming that you are doing regex matches using the pattern attribute, overall it is very unclear.

Comment: I'm sorry, i just added my js repo to the project. That was my bad.